# Trigger - not able to compile/save

Tags: trigger

I am attempting to finish writing my first trigger...ever.  I want to update a field (CampaignMember.Call_Disposition__c) when a task is saved that has a CampaingMember ID and Task.Call_Disposition__c on the task.  Below is the code and I am not seeing where the error is. I see that it reads, "Variable does not exist: cmbr at line 23 column 19"  Any suggestions?

```
trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (after insert) {

    schema.describesobjectresult taskRecordType = CampaignMember.sobjecttype.getdescribe();
    map<string, schema.recordtypeinfo> taskRecordTypeMap = taskRecordType.getrecordtypeinfosbyname();
    id taskRecordTypeId = taskRecordTypeMap.get('CampaignCall').getrecordtypeid();

    Map<Id, CampaignMember> cmpList = new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();
    List<CampaignMember> cmpMap = [Select Id, Call_Disposition__c from CampaignMember];
    List<CampaignMember> cmpUpdateList = new  List<CampaignMember>();

    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {

        IF (t.RecordTypeId = 'CampaignCall' && cmpMap.get(t.whatId) != null) {


            CampaignMember cmbr = new CampaignMember();
            cmbr.Id = t.WhatId;


            cmbr.Call_Disposition__c = t.Call_Disposition__c;
        }

        cmpUpdateList.add(cmbr);
        if (!cmpUpdateList.isEmpty())
            update cmpList;
    }
}
```

****I moved cmpUpdateList.add(cmbr); inside the loop.  Now I get "Error: AND operator can only be applied to Boolean expressions at line 13 column 44" for this line of code:

IF (t.RecordTypeId = 'CampaignCall' && t.Campaign_Member_ID__c != null){

Comment: Hi Lori,   CampaignMember cmbr = new CampaignMember(); cmbr declared inside the if condition but also used out side the ifloop, so place the 23 rd line inside the if condition.

Comment: I've addressed your second issue also.

Comment: Is it compiling now?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I think I may just be in way over my head.  I keep getting more errors for each one I fix.  Perhaps my logic is not what I thought it was....looks like I need to start again.

Answer (score 2):

Move `cmpUpdateList.add(cmbr);` inside the `if` loop.

**EDIT** Also change your if loop to (note the `==` rather than `=`:

```
IF (t.RecordTypeId == 'CampaignCall' && cmpMap.get(t.whatId) != null){
```

You are being bitten by block level scope. If you define a variable inside a loop, it's only visible inside that loop.

Plus, since you are looping, if you add a variable like that outside a loop, assuming you had defined the variable above the loop, it would only add the last value assigned in the loop.

From the docs:

> The following is an example of a local variable whose scope is the duration of the if code block:

```
integer foo = 5;
Boolean myCondition = true;
if (myCondition) {
    integer foo = 10;
}
```

For more information on Apex scope look [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_static.htm).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I appreciate the extra resources as well.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are trying to access variable "cmbr" outside its scope. Please find updated code :

```
trigger CallDispositionOnCampaignMember on Task (after insert) {

    schema.describesobjectresult taskRecordType=CampaignMember.sobjecttype.getdescribe();
    map<string,schema.recordtypeinfo> taskRecordTypeMap=taskRecordType.getrecordtypeinfosbyname();
    id taskRecordTypeId= taskRecordTypeMap.get('CampaignCall').getrecordtypeid();

    Map<Id, CampaignMember> cmpList =new Map<Id, CampaignMember>();
    List<CampaignMember> cmpMap= [Select Id, Call_Disposition__c from CampaignMember];
    List<CampaignMember> cmpUpdateList= new  List<CampaignMember>();

    for (Task t : Trigger.new) {

        IF (t.RecordTypeId == 'CampaignCall' && cmpMap.get(t.whatId) != null){


            CampaignMember cmbr = new CampaignMember();
            cmbr.Id = t.WhatId;


            cmbr.Call_Disposition__c = t.Call_Disposition__c;
            cmpUpdateList.add(cmbr);
        } 
        if(!cmpUpdateList.isEmpty())
            update cmpList;
    }
}
```

Please note, i have not verified logic in this code, only tried to remove compiler error.